# geting data from http.get and effecting it to an object

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

when i run this code i get my desciplines array full of data

```
 onGetDescs(descipline:string){
    let rep  =this.http.get("http://data");
    let result: any;
    rep.subscribe( data => {
      this.desciplines = data as Descipline[];
        result =  this.desciplines.filter(function(d) {
        return d.name === descipline;
      });
      this.desciplines = result as Descipline[];
      console.log(this.desciplines);
    });  

    
     return this.desciplines;
  }
```

but when i run i want to work with it or just to do this

```
  onGetDescs(descipline:string){
    let rep  =this.http.get("http://45.80.149.82:8080/ctp-api/api/disciplines");
    let result: any;
    rep.subscribe( data => {
      this.desciplines = data as Descipline[];
      result =  this.desciplines.filter(function(d) {
      return d.nom === descipline;
      });
      this.desciplines = result as Descipline[];
    });  

    console.log(this.desciplines);

     return this.desciplines;
  }
```

i get an empty array

i really need to know what's happening ps: i'm new to angular

Answer (score 1):

The difference probably between both of those snippets it's the time it is taking for the discipline data to download.

You need to know that the function you pass on to the **subscribe method** will be executed after the data is downloaded, but it **doesn't block execution**, so after you run rep.subscribe(...) the next statement (return this.desciplines;) is practically immediately executed, not giving enough time for the array to be loaded before returning.

What you need to do here is to re-think your logic so that the desired behavior you want to achieve with the discipline data goes inside the subscribe method.

Comment: can i stop the execution until i get the data like a loading popup window

Comment: There's no "stopping execution", but you can add a loading spinner or similar if you want to. Just set a variable in your component called this.loading = true; before calling the subscribe method, and on the 'complete' callback of the subscribe method set it to false. Then on the HTML template use this variable to display or hide the spinner.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on observables to have a better understanding on the subject https://angular.io/guide/observables.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you print the data after the api call sends the data back. (After the async operation)

But in the second case you print data just after calling the api. At this point the api has not sent back data and you will have an empty array.

As I recall the js content runs on a single thread (Happy to be wrong), So the API response (execution of content inside `.subscribe(...)`) will happen after the execution of `onGetDescs`.

Comment: can i stop the execution until i get the data like a loading popup window

Comment: You cannot stop execution of the get call once sent. (well should be possible in very low level of things). But you can certainly block the UI using a modal dialog or provide the end user a visual indication of data being loaded and the user will not be able to interact with the UI. or you can provide a visual clue of loading using a font-awesome loading icon by conditionally displaying with a bool that you set to `true` just before'`.subscribe` and set to `false` after the get is resolved or error-ed out